# Eel server crashes when computer sleeps

Tags: python, google-chrome, sockets, eel

I'm using Eel version 0.14.0

Whenever I'm running an eel project, once the computer sleeps and I eventually turn it back on, I've found that the command window has closed and when I reload the page, I get the error localhost refused to connect. This issue persists even when the program is converted to an exe using pyinstaller and even when the program in run in IDLE. This happens with EVERY eel project I've made using v0.14.0

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

- Create any eel app
- Run the app
- Make your computer sleep
- Wake up computer
- Reload page
- Stare in confusion at the error

Before computer sleeps(Command window/server still open):

[image: example]

After computer sleeps(Command window/server closed):

[image]

Eel window after computer sleeps:

[image: example3]

- OS: Windows
- Browser: Chrome
- Version: 93